# What are the end and coend of Hom in Set?

Tags: category-theory, permutations, trace, limits-colimits, young-tableaux

A functor $F$ of the form $C^{op} \times C \to D$ may have an end $\int_c F(c, c)$ or a coend $\int^c F(c, c)$, as described for example in [nLab](https://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/end) or [Categories for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/03/29/ends-and-coends/). I'm trying to get an intuition for this using concrete examples, and the most obvious example of such an $F$ is the Hom functor on the category of sets. However, trying to calculate the coend has not gotten me very far, although I suspect that the equivalence class of an endomorphism is related to its [eventual image](https://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/eventual+image).

Is there a nice description of the end and coend in this case?

And (extra credit) are there other good candidates for the first nontrivial concrete example of an end or coend?

Comment: "Categorical Homotopy Theory" has a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end is pretty easy. An element of the end is a choice of endomorphism $\alpha_S$ for each set $S$, such that the endomorphisms commute with all functions: for any $f: S \to T$, $f \circ \alpha_S = \alpha_T \circ f$. It's clear that $\text{id}$, the collection of identity maps, is such an element. Also, if we choose $S = \{*\}$ then it's clear that $\alpha_T$ must fix every $t \in T$. So the end has only the single element $\text{id}$.

The coend (as others have said) is harder. But here's a pretty good description. I think it's equivalent to @Kyle Miller's, but with some details filled in.

We have the functor $\operatorname{Hom}: \operatorname{Set}^{\operatorname{op}} \times \operatorname{Set} \to \operatorname{Set}$. The coend $\int^S \operatorname{Hom}(S, S)$ would be a set with maps $i_X: \operatorname{Hom}(X, X) \to \int^X$ for all $X$, which is a *universal cowedge*.
For the "universal" part, we just take $\coprod_X \operatorname{Hom}(X, X)$.
For "cowedge", we need the square
from $\operatorname{Hom}(Y, X) \to \int^S$ to commute for any $f: X \to Y$.
That is, $i_X \cdot (- \cdot f) = i_Y \cdot (f \cdot -)$, where $- \cdot f: \operatorname{Hom}(Y, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(X, X)  $ and $f \cdot -: \operatorname{Hom}(Y, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(Y, Y)$.
The cowedge condition gives a relation between endomorphisms of sets: if we have endomorphisms $\phi$ of $X$ and $\psi$ of $Y$, and if they are related via functions $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ such that $gf = \phi$ and $fg = \psi$, we will say $\phi W \psi$.
Then $\int^S$ would be $\coprod_X \operatorname{Hom}(X, X) / \sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $W$.
So our main goal is to describe $\sim$.
(Here we are taking a coproduct over a proper class, but we will ignore size issues throughout.)

Here's a description of $\sim$. Fix an endomorphism $\sigma$ in $\operatorname{Set}$. We'll describe the equivalence class $[\sigma]$ under $\sim$.

Some endomorphisms are conjugate: for endomorphisms $\phi_0$, $\phi_1$ of $X_0$, $X_1$ respectively, we will say $\phi_0 \simeq \phi_1$ if there is an isomorphism $\alpha: X_0 \to X_1$ such that $\phi_1 = \alpha \phi_0 \alpha^{-1}$. For $i \ge 0$, define $D^i$ as all $\phi$ such that $\phi | _{\phi^i[X] \to \phi^i[X]} \simeq \sigma$ (where  $\phi: X \to X$). Then define $D = \bigcup_i D^i$.

**I claim** that $[\sigma] = D$.
First we show $[\sigma] \subseteq D$. Clearly $\sigma \in D^0$. So it's enough to show that for $i \ge 0$, if $\phi \in D^i$ and $\phi W \psi$, then $\psi \in D^{i + 1}$. So suppose we have $X$, $Y$, $f$, $g$ witnessing $\phi W \psi$. Take $\bar X = \phi^i[X]$ and $\bar \phi = \phi | _{\bar X \to \bar X}$, so $\bar \phi \simeq \sigma$. Take $\bar Y = f[\bar X]$, and note $g[\bar Y] = \bar X$, so we can define $\bar f = f | _{\bar X \to \bar Y}$ and $\bar g = g | _{\bar Y \to \bar X}$. Then $\bar \phi = g | _{f[\bar X]} f | _{\bar X} = \bar g \bar f$. Since $\bar \phi$ is an automorphism, $\bar f$ is mono; and $\bar f$ is epi by construction, and therefore an isomorphism. And $\bar g = \bar \phi {\bar f}^{-1}$ is also an isomorphism.

Now take $\bar \psi = \psi | _{\bar Y \to \bar Y}$. Not surprisingly, $\bar \psi = f | _{gf[\bar X]} g | _{f[\bar X]} = \bar f \bar g$. Note that $\psi^{i + 1} = f \phi^i g$. So we have $\psi^{i + 1}[Y] \subseteq f \phi^i[X] = f[\bar X]$. But also $\psi^{i + 1}[Y] \supseteq f \phi^i g[\bar Y] = f \phi^i[\bar X] = f[\bar X]$. So $\psi^{i + 1}[Y] = f[\bar X] = \bar Y$. Now $\psi | _{\psi^{i + 1}[Y] \to \psi^{i + 1}[Y]} = \psi | _{\bar Y \to \bar Y} = \bar \psi = \bar f \bar g \simeq \bar g(\bar f \bar g){\bar g}^{-1} = \bar \phi \simeq \sigma$. This means $\psi \in D^{i + 1}$ as required, so $[\sigma] \subseteq D$.

To show $D \subseteq [\sigma]$, we need to show that all $D^i \subseteq [\sigma]$, so again we work by induction. If $\phi \in D^0$, then $\phi \simeq \sigma$, so $\alpha \phi \alpha^{-1}$ for some $\alpha$; then taking $f = \alpha \phi$ and $g = \alpha^{-1}$, we see that $\phi W \sigma$. So $D^0 \subseteq [\sigma]$. Now suppose $D^i \subseteq [\sigma]$ for some $i \ge 0$, and $\psi \in D^{i + 1}$. I claim there is a $\phi \in D^i$ with $\phi W \psi$; this gives $\psi \in [\sigma]$, so $D^{i + 1} \subseteq [\sigma]$ as required.

Say $\psi: Y \to Y$. Take $X = \psi[Y]$, and the epi-mono factorization $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$, $g = \psi | _{Y \to \psi[Y]}$ of $\psi = fg$. Take $\phi = gf = \psi | _{X \to X}$. We get $\phi^i[X] = \psi^i[X] = \psi^{i + 1}[Y]$, so $\phi | _{\phi^i[X]} = \psi | _{\psi^{i + 1}[Y]}$. Since $\psi | _{\psi^{i + 1}[Y]} \simeq \sigma$, we get $\phi | _{\phi^i[X]} \simeq \sigma$ and $\phi \in D^i$, as required. So $D \subseteq [\sigma]$, and $D = [\sigma]$. **Q.E.D.**

In particular, it's easy to describe the two simplest elements of $\int^S$. If $\sigma$ is the endomorphism of the empty set, then it's easy to check that $[\sigma]$ is just the one element $\{\sigma\}$. And if $\sigma$ is the endomorphism of a singleton, then $[\sigma]$ is the class of endomorphisms $\phi$ which are "eventually constant" in the sense that some $\phi^i$ is constant.

The argument also works in $\operatorname{FinSet}$. In this case, the iterated image $\phi[X], \phi^2[X], ...$ eventually settles on a stable subset, so we find that $\phi \sim \sigma$ for an automorphism $\sigma$ of that subset. This means $\int^S$ is the set of conjugacy classes of permutations, or the set of integer partitions.

This appears to be the only reasonably complete answer to the original question.

**EDITED** to add the coend description.

Answer (score 9):

The most important example of an end is $\int_{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{D} (F c, G c)$, where $F$ and $G$ are functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$.
If you unfold the definition you will find that it is the set of natural transformations $F \Rightarrow G$.
In particular, for $F = G = \textrm{id}_\mathcal{C}$, you obtain the fact that $\int_{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C} (c, c)$ is the set of natural transformations  $\textrm{id}_\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \textrm{id}_\mathcal{C}$, which you might call the set of natural endomorphisms for short.

The coend $\int^{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C} (c, c)$ is a stranger thing.
It has to do with factorisations of endomorphisms.
In general, given $H : \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$, the coend $\int^{c : \mathcal{C}} H (c, c)$ is the disjoint union $\coprod_{c \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{C}} H (c, c)$ modulo the smallest equivalence relation $\sim$ such that, given $x \in H (b, a)$ and $f \in \mathcal{C} (a, b)$, we have $H (f, \textrm{id}_a) x \sim H (\textrm{id}_b, f) x$.
For $H (b, a) = \mathcal{C} (b, a)$, this amounts to taking the set of all endomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ modulo the smallest equivalence relation $\sim$ such that, given $x : b \to a$ and $f : a \to b$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $x \circ f \sim f \circ x$.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid then we can describe the equivalence relation explicitly: given automorphisms $y : a \to a$ and $z : b \to b$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $y \sim z$ if and only if there is an isomorphism $f : a \to b$ such that $f \circ y = z \circ f$.
Indeed, if $f \circ y = z \circ f$, then $y = (f^{-1} \circ z) \circ f$ and $z = f \circ (f^{-1} \circ z)$, i.e. $x = f^{-1} \circ z$ in the earlier formula gives us $y \sim z$.
So we may think of $\int^{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C} (c, c)$ as the set of conjugacy classes of automorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid.
If $\mathcal{C}$ is a group considered as a one-object groupoid, then this really is the set of conjugacy classes as defined in elementary group theory.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But surely someone has figured out an explicit description of the coend when $\cal{C} = \Bbb{Set}$.

Answer (score 5):

Playing with the universal property, you get that the set $\int_c\hom_{\cal C}(c,c)$ is the set of natural transformations $\text{id}_{\cal C} \Rightarrow \text{id}_{\cal C}$. I think the easiest way to see this is using the description of $\int_c\hom_{\cal C}(c,c)$ as an equalizer of a pair of maps. Give it a try!

For what concerns the coend... it's not easy: the quotient you have to perform on $\coprod_c\hom_{\cal C}(c,c)$ can vary a lot as the structure of $\cal C$ varies.

Many times I believed I found a general formula, but then a counterexample popped out!

Answer (score 4):

The coend $c=\int^{X:\mathrm{Set}}\hom(X,X)$ seems to be rather subtle, but there is something that can be said. We have a family of maps $\omega_X:\hom(X,X)\to e$ for every set $X$, and these satisfy for all sets $X$ and $Y$ and functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ that $\omega_X(g\circ f)=\omega_Y(f\circ g)$. So the coend is the "universal trace" for sets.

Recall that given $f:X\to X$ that it factors as $f=i\circ s$ with $s:X \to f(X)$ a surjection and $i:f(X)\to X$ the inclusion. Hence, $\omega_X(f)=\omega_X(i\circ s)=\omega_{f(X)}(s\circ i)$. We can restrict the domain of $s$ to $\operatorname{im} f$, giving $f|_{f(X)}$, and so we have that
$$\omega_X(f)=\omega_{f(X)} (f|_{f(X)\to f(X)}).$$
For all $f:X\to X$, let $rf=f|_{f(X)\to f(X)}$ be this restriction, and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $r^nf$ be the $n$-fold iterated restriction. Hence, we have for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that
$$\omega_X(f) = \omega_{f^n(X)}(r^nf).$$
If $X$ is finite, this iterated restriction eventually stabilizes to a bijection, which we will call $\operatorname{core}(f)$. (In fact, in this case its domain $\bigcap_n f^n(X)$ equals $\{x\in X\mid \exists n>0, f^n(x)=x\}$, the set of all elements on which the monoid generated by $f$ acts on with finite order. Infinite sets are more complicated. One thing you can prove is that $f(\bigcap_n f^n(X))=\bigcap_n f^n(X)$ if every fiber of $f$ is finite, a sort of variant of Konig's lemma.) When $f:X\to X$ is a bijection, then given any other bijection $g:X\to X$ we have that $\omega_X(f)=\omega_X(g\circ f\circ g^{-1})$, and so $\omega_X(f)$ gives an invariant of the conjugacy class of $f$. That is, $\omega_X$ can only see the cycle type of $f$.

If we restrict to $\mathrm{FinSet}$, then what we can use as a model for the coend is the set of all multisets of positive natural numbers, where $\omega_X(f)$ maps to the multiset consisting of all the cycle lengths in $\operatorname{core}(f)$.

For general sets, it seems to me that the coend can be described as $\coprod_{X:\mathrm{Set}}\hom(X,X)$ modulo this $r$ operator and conjugation. I'm not sure there's too much more we can say here -- things would be easier if we could just restrict $f$ to $\bigcap_n f^n(X)$, but the coend is telling us rich information about the behavior when $n$ is *near* infinity, not just when it's "at" infinity.

Comment: Nice! I see that in the [nLab derivation of the "trace" of FinSet](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/trace+of+a+category), they arrive at the same set of equivalence classes: the conjugacy classes of permutations. The use of the epi-mono factorization makes me wonder if there is some generalization from Set to toposes.

Comment: For completeness: the equivalence classes can also be viewed as Young diagrams, or multisets of positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

This question was originally studied (in the context of enriched categories) in Lindner's [Center and trace](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01235372). The end of the hom functor of a $\mathscr V$-category $\mathcal C$ is called its *centre*, and the coend is called its *trace*. The trace for $\mathscr V = \mathbf{Set}$ is specifically treated in (4.8) Example 3.

Comment: It seems they compute the trace for the category of finite sets, not all sets.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: they compute the trace for an arbitary small category, and then specialise to the category of finite sets, where the trace has a simpler form.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I see now that you mean the specific case of categories enriched over Set, not the trace of the category Set.